# iOS16 beta5 crash

Tags: crash, ios16, xcode14

[image]

on iOS16 beta5, our app crash on much sceniroes, such as app launch, search result and so on.
the crash stack is the same as above.

we found a scenario that when we present a UIAlertController, and click a botton to excute a block, the block post a notification, and the notification received by more than 7 observers, the crash will 100% happen.

and when the app crash, the console will print 'Pre-fence handler registered, but not invoked: handlersCount=%u, transactionState=0x%x'